# What to do with idol worship relics or impure objects

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah

Once knowing the truth of the Torah, and the seven noahide laws,I disposed of many things. I want to know how exactly are you to dispose of these things.( Parashat Re'eh) gives a set of instructions on what to do once the Nation of isreal enter eretz Israel Im wandering if the same procedure is expected for a non Jew